# Linux bash script which fails to generate expected result

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to linux programming and is currently learning it at college. I understood my question might be a bit long and I apologize for it first as I really do not know where I went wrong... I came across a problem as follow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJHS.png)

I have written the codes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    for file in *.txt         
do
    echo "$file"
    b="$1"
    a="`grep $b $file`"
        if [ "$a" ]
        then
            cat $file | grep '$1' | sort >> $1.'txt'
        else
            echo "No records found for $1"
        fi
        done
else
    echo "Usage: ./Train_trace.sh <train ID>"
fi
```

The above codes hope to satisfy the question1.2 requirement but I really do not know where are my problems and lead to an unsuccessful result for two days already. I really hope someone could give me some hints. Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you done so far to try to debug your script? You can trace it or put in extra echoes to try and see where it may be failing. But as it stands, it's not a well-formed stackoverflow.com question since you've presented your code, a detailed problem/question in an image, and are just saying you have a problem somewhere without much additional information.

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Learn how to format code for this site.

Comment: *"The above codes hope to satisfy the question1.2 requirement..."* - What requirement are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems.  One good approach is use the line

```
set -x
```

as the second line of your file.  This shows the interpretation of each line as it is executed, and will help you identify problems.

I suggest you use meaningful variable names. For example, use 'train_id' instead of 'b'.  Also, once you've assigned $1 to a variable, use the variable, don't use $1.

When you surround a variable with single quote -- '$foo', the variable won't be interpreted.

To help us help you more, add a few lines of an input file.  Using an image file in a question is strongly discouraged.  People that want to help you are forced to re-type the information from the image, and it's too long a process to encourage answers.